# Ease into model rotation

Tags: c#, 3d, matrix, xna

I'm making a simple game in XNA (for Windows, if that makes a difference), and when the player moves right, I'm using the following code to rotate the ship model to make it look like the ship is leaning into the strafe:

```
RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) *
                 Matrix.CreateRotationY(0.4f);
```

That works, but it instantly pops the ship to the desired rotation. I would rather it ease in over a few frames. For reference, the rotation matrix was declared as follows:

```
public Matrix RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2);
```

What can I do to smooth the lean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that You just need to include time into your code. In Xna, you have access to `GameTime`  object (in `Game.Draw` method, for example ), so, you may try something like this:

```
private float _seconds = 0;
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (_seconds < 1)
    {
        _seconds += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }
    RotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) *
         Matrix.CreateRotationY(0.4f * _seconds);
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

From place I'm now, I cannot check if this code is valid, so this is only idea ;).

Comment: Yeah, that works. I ended up making the variable a public float in the ship class so that I could keep track of it more easily. Thanks!